# Jellyfin hardware acceleration `iHD_drv_video.so init failed` error

Tags: linux, ubuntu, jellyfin

I'm trying to setup a hardware acceleration for my laptop linux homeserver.

I've followed the guideline from the official doc: `https://jellyfin.org/docs/general/administration/hardware-acceleration/intel#configure-with-linux-virtualization`

### Here is my setup:

1. running `Jellyfin` with `docker-compose`
2. hardware spec:

```
    product: HP Pavilion TS Sleekbook 14 (D1G64UA#ABA)
    vendor: Hewlett-Packard
    version: 0883110014355900000320120
    serial: 
    width: 64 bits
    capabilities: smbios-2.7 dmi-2.7 smp vsyscall32
...

     *-cpu
          description: CPU
          product: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3337U CPU @ 1.80GHz
          vendor: Intel Corp.
          physical id: 20
          bus info: cpu@0
          version: 6.58.9
          serial: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
          slot: U3E1
          size: 1723MHz
          capacity: 4GHz
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 100MHz
          capabilities: lm fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp x86-64 constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm cpuid_fault epb pti ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp fsgsbase smep erms xsaveopt dtherm ida arat pln pts md_clear flush_l1d cpufreq
          configuration: cores=2 enabledcores=2 microcode=33 threads=4
```

3. the QSV and VA-API codecs I get when I run `docker exec -it jellyfin /usr/lib/jellyfin-ffmpeg/vainfo`

### Here is my problem:

1. When I run `docker exec -it jellyfin /usr/lib/jellyfin-ffmpeg/ffmpeg -v verbose -init_hw_device vaapi=va -init_hw_device opencl@va` I get this error:

```
...
[AVHWDeviceContext @ 0x558e56f084c0] Trying to use DRM render node for device 0.
[AVHWDeviceContext @ 0x558e56f084c0] libva: VA-API version 1.18.0
[AVHWDeviceContext @ 0x558e56f084c0] libva: Trying to open /usr/lib/jellyfin-ffmpeg/lib/dri/iHD_drv_video.so
[AVHWDeviceContext @ 0x558e56f084c0] libva: Found init function __vaDriverInit_1_18
[AVHWDeviceContext @ 0x558e56f084c0] libva: /usr/lib/jellyfin-ffmpeg/lib/dri/iHD_drv_video.so init failed
[AVHWDeviceContext @ 0x558e56f084c0] libva: va_openDriver() returns 1
[AVHWDeviceContext @ 0x558e56f084c0] libva: Trying to open /usr/lib/jellyfin-ffmpeg/lib/dri/i965_drv_video.so
[AVHWDeviceContext @ 0x558e56f084c0] libva: Found init function __vaDriverInit_1_18
[AVHWDeviceContext @ 0x558e56f084c0] libva: va_openDriver() returns 0
[AVHWDeviceContext @ 0x558e56f084c0] Initialised VAAPI connection: version 1.18
[AVHWDeviceContext @ 0x558e56f084c0] VAAPI driver: Intel i965 driver for Intel(R) Ivybridge Mobile - 2.4.0.pre1 ().
[AVHWDeviceContext @ 0x558e56f084c0] Driver not found in known nonstandard list, using standard behaviour.
[AVHWDeviceContext @ 0x558e56f22c80] Failed to get number of OpenCL platforms: -1001.
Device creation failed: -19.
Failed to set value 'opencl@va' for option 'init_hw_device': No such device
Error parsing global options: No such device
```

Any advice or feedback will be much appreicated.